# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anaconda 5.2 + Python 3.6 + Visual Studio 2017

Очень странное поведение, в строке

```
memo[n] = fib3(n - 1) + fib3(n - 2)
```

программа падает с ошибкой.

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
from typing import Dict

memo: Dict[int, int] = {0: 0, 1: 1} # базовые случаи

def fib3(n):
    if n not in memo:
       memo[n] = fib3(n - 1) + fib3(n - 2) # мемоизация
       return memo[n]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fib3(50))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если условие не выполняется

```
if n not in memo:
```

То `return` нет.

Нужно выдвинуть `return` из-под `if`

```
def fib3(n):
    if n not in memo:
       memo[n] = fib3(n - 1) + fib3(n - 2) # мемоизация
    return memo[n]
```